# Load Image Random in Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap

I am making a game and i would like to load background images to canvas.ie background should load random from array and should be different.This is the code that i used

```
    int[] wallpaper={R.drawable.bg,R.drawable.bg_two,R.drawable.bg_three,R.drawable.bg_four, };

      if(globalBitmap == null){
        Random random = new Random();
        int n=random.nextInt(wallpaper.length);
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(wallpaper[n]);
        globalBitmap = bd.getBitmap();
    }
    this.bitmap = globalBitmap;
```

But when ever i load game.Only same background gets displayed.All 4 background doesn't load in random order.Can any one help to solve this?

Logcat

```
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518): Process: com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun, PID: 10518
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3022)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.Background.getRandom(Background.java:37)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.Background.testMethod(Background.java:43)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.Background.<init>(Background.java:30)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.Frontground.<init>(Frontground.java:19)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:50)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.themebowlapps.monkeyrun.Game.onCreate(Game.java:41)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1259)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
02-14 14:38:04.757: E/AndroidRuntime(10518):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In which method is the above code being executed? In what scope is `globalBitmap` defined?

Comment: Please, post more details code.

Answer (score 0):

Your globalBitmap only load once time...Try this code, maybe help u

```
    int[] wallpaper={R.drawable.bg,R.drawable.bg_two,R.drawable.bg_three,R.drawable.bg_four, };
    BitmapDrawable getRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int n = random.nextInt(wallpaper.length);
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(wallpaper[n]);
        return bd.getBitmap();  
    }

    void testMethod() {
        this.bitmap = getRandom();
    }
```

Comment: I think your method works.But i get out of memory error.So i couldn't make sure if it works properly.Because as soon as app force quit and i load app once again i get different background.so is there a way to get rid of out of memory error.I used png images first, now jpeg still i get that error.

Comment: I think your image too big, try to resize your image, and recycle() your bitmap before release it

Comment: Where exactly should i use bitmap.recycle(); ?

Comment: Before load new image.

Comment: can you tell me where exactly in above code should i add recycle() ?

Answer (score 0):

You get an `OutOfMemoryError` which means the environment you are running your app in doesn't have enough memory available to fully load the bitmap you are trying to load.

The solution is to load a scaled down version of the image so that it fits in memory. All the details how to do this are given and explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), take a look at it and reuse their `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource()` method instead of just calling `Resources#getDrawable()`.
Note that you should always load you images like this, unless you are completely sure of the size of the original image.

Then, there is also the problem that you don't know first hand how much memory you have available, so that you can't know the `reqWidth` and `reqHeight` which will enable you to load an image for sure without an out of memory error happening. That's why I usually wrap the call to decode the image in a `try` block catching the `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions, and loop around it to retry loading a smaller version of the images in case of error until finding a loadable size.
Something in this flavor (disclaimer: code not tested):

```
final int imageResourceId = ...;  // do your random selection here
Bitmap loadedBitmap = null;
int reqWidth = DEFAULT_REQ_WIDTH, reqHeight = DEFAULT_REQ_HEIGHT;
while (loadedBitmap == null && reqWidth >= MIN_REQ_WIDTH && reqHeight >= MIN_REQ_HEIGHT) {
    try {
        loadedBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), imageResourceId, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    } catch (final OutOfMemoryError oOM) {
        // not enough memory to load an image this size, retry with a smaller one
        reqWidth /= 2;
        reqHeight /= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,so can you tell me how to modify above mentioned code?ie i need to load images from array to canvas and it shouldn't have outof memory error

Comment: Yes, this is what I just intended to do by answering your question. Try to read it and understand what it means (and don't forget to do the same with the linked article) and you should see how to modify your given code. I'm happy to further explain something unclear or that you don't understand, but I can't write your code for you ; this is a only an "explain me" Q&A site not a "do it for me" freelancer dispatch site :)